# php - how to loop through values of one specific key in an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

**I am new to php**, I have an associative array like this

```
$arr['Joe'] = "test1";
$arr['Joe'] = "test2";
$arr['Joe'] = "test3";
```

how do I loop through all the values `test1, test2, test3` of this specific key `Joe`?

I tried this

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

and this

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $arr [$key]['Joe'];
}
```

But nothing ! Please help me?

Comment: You can't have multiple keys with the same name. In your case `Joe` will always be `test3`.

Comment: oh! I didn't know that, is there any other ways to hold multiple values in an associative array?

Comment: Yes. arrays of arrays.

Comment: you are setting the values wrong to the array, do this instead `$arr['Joe'][0] = "test1";` etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<?php

$arr['Joe'][] = "test1";
$arr['Joe'][] = "test2";
$arr['Joe'][] = "test3";

foreach ($arr['Joe'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

By adding [] after ['Joe'] the values will be saved like this:

```
(
    [Joe] => Array
        (
            [0] => test1
            [1] => test2
            [2] => test3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

To hold multiple values in an associative array they each need to be unique.
eg.

```
$arr['Joe1'] = "test1";
$arr['Joe2'] = "test2";
$arr['Joe3'] = "test3";
```

and then

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```